# Javascript: check IF page is at the top

Tags: javascript, scroll

**Is there a way to check, with JavaScript, if the page is at `scroll(0,0)`?**

Reason being I've got a full page slider that I need to pause the second the page is not at origin.

And it might not necessarily be because the page is being scrolled live as I've got internal HTML # links that would load the page right to a scrolled point without actually scrolling.

So the check needs to be is the page not at the top, as opposed to, has the page been scrolled.

Answer (score 38):

You can check if [`window.scrollY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY) (the number of pixels the window has scrolled vertically) is equal to `0`. If you want to check if the window has been scrolled to its leftermost, you can check if [`window.scrollX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollX) (the number of pixels the window has scrolled horizontally) is equal to `0`. If you combine the two, it will ensure the window is at (0,0) position.

```
if(window.scrollY==0){
 //user scrolled to the top of the page
}
if(window.scrollX==0){
 //user scrolled to the leftmost part of the page
}
if(window.scrollY==0&&window.scrollX==0){
  //user scrolled to the leftmost part of the top of the page—i.e., they are at position (0, 0)
}
```

Demo:

```js
var goToTop = document.querySelector('#backToTop');
goToTop.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  window.scroll({top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
  //scroll smoothly back to the top of the page
});
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  if(window.scrollY==0){
    //user is at the top of the page; no need to show the back to top button
    goToTop.style.display = "";
  } else {
    goToTop.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```css
body,html{height:3000px;position:relative;margin:0}#footer{position:absolute;width:100%;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;background-color:#1e90ff;text-align:center}#backToTop{position:fixed;right:0;bottom:0;display:none;z-index:1}#header{position:absolute;width:100%;top:0;left:0;right:0;background-color:#1e90ff;text-align:center}
```

```html
<div id="header">Header</div>
<button id="backToTop">Back To Top</button>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

For better browser compatibility, use [`window.pageYOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset) instead of `window.scrollY` and [`window.pageXOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageXOffset) instead of `window.scrollX`.

The following code can be used in cases when full browser compatability is necessary (i.e., IE < 9):

```
var x = (window.pageXOffset !== undefined)
  ? window.pageXOffset
  : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollLeft;
//number of pixels scrolled horizontally (work with this value instead of window.scrollX or window.pageXOffset)

var y = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined)
  ? window.pageYOffset
  : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
//number of pixels scrolled vertically (work with this value instead of window.scrollY or window.pageYOffset)
```

Comment: this works well - it is the standard method i use, just a little suggestion to use === instead of ==. Just because of semantics :) strict comparison instead of type conversion can go a long way, and it looks sexier ;)

Comment: @geostima Strict equality is unnecessary because `window.scrollX` and `window.scrollY` can only return numeric values; as such, even using `if(!window.scrollY)console.log('scrolled to top');` would be fine albeit less readable.

Answer (score 36):

Try this:

```
document.body.scrollTop === 0
```

Comment: This simply doesn't work.

Comment: @GregTomasik use `window.scrollY`

Answer (score 10):

**Updated Answer for 2019**

document.body.scrollTop is deprecated and doesn't work at all in Chrome anymore. The best way to solve this is simply looking at all three possibilities to have a cross browser solution.

```
!window.pageYOffset
```

One of these three should work on all browser types.  If the value equals 0, your at the top of the viewport.

Comment: "document.body.scrollTop === 0" will always return true.

Comment: in Chrome I believe?  Other browsers I don't think so?

Answer (score 5):

i think you can get the position using jQuery `$(window).scrollTop()`