# Hide div when in top of page with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide a div when the page is scrolled to top and to show it when it is not with jquery.

Any way to do so?

Edit: by hide and show I mean fade in and fade out.

Comment: .scrollTop() (http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) and the "scroll" event should be helpful.

Comment: @ViruZX Just FYI, a downvote is intended to mean: `This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a combination of scroll event and `scrollTop()`

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPos <= 0) {
        $(".theDivNeedsHiding").fadeOut();
    } else {
        $(".theDivNeedsHiding").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Edit: updated the `scrollTop` query, as jQuery provides a compatibility layer if the element is the `window`.

Comment: any chance of hiding it by default with jquery or css?

Comment: You can just make the div `display: hidden;` by default, or have `$(window).trigger("scroll");` after this code.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `scroll` event, and check `document.body.scrollTop` (SO: [Javascript: check IF page is at top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218159/javascript-check-if-page-is-at-top))

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(document.body.scrollTop == 0) {
        $("#hello").fadeOut();
    } else {
        $("#hello").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edz4u2fg/)

Comment: `document.body.scrollTop` only works in WebKit browsers. In Firefox, the main scrolling element is the `<html>` element.

Comment: thanks for clarifying @Zenorbi, then your answer is more correct. Does `$(window).scrollTop()` work regardless of WebKit/Firefox do you know? Instead of checking both `html` and `body`?

Comment: I just tested it and looked into jQuery's source code. Yes it does work, as jQuery uses a special way of accessing the `scrollTop` when you query the `window`. If the element is a `window`, it tries to look for the `pageYOffset`. If there isn't a property called that, it then tries `document.documentElement.scrollTop`.

Comment: cool, thanks for looking it up, that seems like the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.Scroll down and when you come back it disappears. http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/78sfqm57/

```js
var $toTop = $('#toTop');
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $toTop.fadeIn();
  } else if ($toTop.is(':visible')) {
    $toTop.fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toTop" style="height:1000px;">
      I am gonna hide if you scoll up agaain!
</div>
```