# How to make sure the scrollTo(0,0) has moved the scroll to top of the page?

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrolltop, scrollto

If I have to perform some action post the scrolling to the top of page, how would I have to make sure that page is scrolled to the top of the page.

P.S.: something like promise, the moment it scrolls up, I should be able to call a call back

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: check IF page is at top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218159/javascript-check-if-page-is-at-top)

Comment: hey all, I asked for something like promise, the moment the it scrolls up, I should be able to call back.

Comment: Nope it is not a duplicate question and I have checked all the existing answers already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically which checking if top position.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   function clicked(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    var top = (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop)  - (document.documentElement.clientTop || 0);
    if(top == 0){
     //Do something here
     console.log("do")
    }
    else{
     clicked();
    }
   }
  </script>
  <style>
   button{margin-top:600px;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <button onClick="clicked()">Click Me</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer serves the purpose

Answer (score 0):

If `document.documentElement.scrollTop` is equal to 0, you are on top of your page