# Not recognising when scrolled to top

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add and remove some classes depending on the scroll position. The problem in my code is that it's not doing my `else if` conditions.

Also, can I use any other measurements? Such as `document.body.scrollTop < 25%`

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop < 800 || document.documentElement.scrollTop < 800) {
    document.querySelector(".navbar").classList.add('nav-dark');
  } else if(document.body.scrollTop === 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop === 0){
    document.querySelector(".navbar").classList.add('nav-transparent');
    document.querySelector(".navbar").classList.remove('nav-dark');
  }
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

0 will always be less than 800; as such, you need to change the order of your statements.

```
if(document.body.scrollTop === 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop === 0){
    document.querySelector(".navbar").classList.add('nav-dark');
} else if (document.body.scrollTop < 800 || document.documentElement.scrollTop < 800) {
    document.querySelector(".navbar").classList.add('nav-transparent');
    document.querySelector(".navbar").classList.remove('nav-dark');
}
```

Your code can be simplified by using `window.pageYOffset` instead to get the vertical amount scrolled. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218159/javascript-check-if-page-is-at-top/51698993#51698993) if you want a robust cross browser solution.

```
if(window.pageYOffset === 0){
    document.querySelector(".navbar").classList.add('nav-dark');
} else if (window.pageYOffset < 800) {
    document.querySelector(".navbar").classList.add('nav-transparent');
    document.querySelector(".navbar").classList.remove('nav-dark');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the condition i..e move condition with 0 first and then < 800. Since 0 is also less than 800 that's why it is not going into else if block.